# stop my "google sites CMS" website from being indexed on google?

Tags: html, content-management-system, robots.txt, google-sites, google-index

I used it just for fun **google sites** while a ago,

unfortunately, the website becomes viewable on google when I search with my name.

*what do I want?*

I want to not make it visible anymore when someone searches,

but I don't want to delete it 100%, by this I mean if someone uses the link is still viewable.

I know that there is a lot of similar question on StackOverflow,

 but in this case, the **CMS doesn't** make me add the `robot.txt` with this code `User-agent: * Disallow: /`

*here is the link to CMS:*

https://sites.google.com/new

*why do I want to hide it?*

the website doesn't contain useful info,

 in that time I didn't know HTML and CSS,

 now I can make it better in less time

Is very bad seeing your name on a very bad-looking website, once now I can do better. is not a good impression to do.

*If you want to know when I created that website?*

> very while ago, December 2020

[image]

*what I tried?*

I tried to see "setting" in their UI, but nothing.

[image]

---

for more info tell me I will tell you everything you need.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** yes there is a way in "google sites", here it is

[image]

---

**how?**

1. go to your website editor.
   2 then you will see a colored button with the text "publish" (maybe in your language it will be something similar)
   [image]

> don't click it, for now, just find it then go to the next step (is in the navbar at the top right)

3. once you find it, click the arrow part of the button

[image]

4. click "publish settings" (not the icon but the text)

[image]

5. here it will open a popup (see the first image in this answer)
6. activate the Search settings checkbox input, by clicking it

[image]

7. save

---

finish, the website will not be indexed anymore

> (it may take more hours/minutes before it will take effect but it will work)

Comment: ok, I will try to see if I can do it